# Prove that if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f(a)\cdot f(b)<0, \Rightarrow \exists c \in (a, b)$ such that $ f(c) = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I need to prove that if $ f $ is continuous on $ [a, b] $ and $ f(a) \cdot f(b) \lt 0 $, then $ \exists c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f(c) = 0 $. In the exercise, they suggested the following:

A close interval $ [m, t]\subseteq [a, b] $ is called $ good $ iff $ f(m) \lt 0 \lt f(d) $. First prove that if $ [m,t] $ and $ m $ is the midpoint of $ [m, t] $, then $ f(m) = 0 $ or at least one of the close intervals, $ [c, m], [m, d]$ is good. Later, construct a sequence of intervals to help you prove the statement.

I understand what they're trying to say, but can't I just use the fact that $ f $ is continuous, and $ f(a) \lt 0 \lt f(b) $ and say that according to the intermediate value theorem, there exists $ c \in (a, b) $ such that $ f(c) = 0 $.

Comment: If IVT has been proven before in the text, sure... I would guess, though, that it has not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the Bolzano theorem, and yes, its an inmediate corollary from the Intermediate values theorem.
Anyway, it can be proven in such many ways without the IVM. For example with the nested interval propertie( is similar idea as the suggested). A very simple proof is the following:

Let $I$ a closed and bounded interval of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f$ continuous in $I$. Then $f(I)$ is also a closed bounded interval. Since $f(I)$ is an interval, and $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)$ then $[f(a),f(b)]\subset f(I)$, so $[f(a),f(b)]$ it's also a closed bounded interval such as $0\in[f(a),f(b)]$. It implies that there exist $c\in(a,b)$, such as $f(c)=0$

Comment: One must be careful here to avoid circular reasoning. How do you prove that the continuous image of an interval is again an interval? Without using the IVT or Bolzano's theorem?

Comment: The only connected subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are the invertals. The continuous image of a connected set is connected, hence it must be an interval